# New Tensorflow library

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to make new tensorflow library ? For e.g. I want to write some tensorflow code, matrix multiplication:

```
# File custom_matmul.py

import tensorflow as tf

matrixA = ...
matrixB = ...

matrixC = tf.matmul(...)
```

And in another python file, I want to do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.custom_matmul...
```

Or make library to be part of library layers

```
tf.layers.custom_matmul
```

Much more simpler, I want to make my own library and integrate it to the standard tensorflow library/framework.

Comment: Why don't you just make a module and use the attributes it exposes?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making your own module that imports and extends tensorflow the way you want rather than changing the source. For example

```
import tensorflow as tf
import mytf
```

Then you could do

```
mytf.layers.custom_matmul
```

you could even, within mytf, expose your own attributes to tensorflow. I wouldn't recommend this because it would be confusing to anyone reading your code (including possibly yourself in the future), but you could

```
tf.layers.custom_matmul = MyCustomMatMul()
```

you could then use tf.layers.custom_matmul as described in the question. Again, not recommended.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That's one option, but if I want to change TF, is that possible, like I want to do that ?

Comment: I'll direct you here. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: You can fork it and use it directly